# Android: How to iterate multiple JSON object Arrays in the same file

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have tried searching for this problem and solution but i haven't found any. I have a JSON file which has information about locations, each has an array of images like this

```
    {
"locations": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Alibey Island (Cunda)",
        "destination_id": 2,
        "string_info": "Otherwise known as Cunda, Alibey Island is connected to Lale Island and Ayvalık by a road bridge. Accordingly, dolmuşes and buses are available from the mainland if you don’t have your own transportation. <br />\r\n<br />\r\nOn the north edge of Cunda, look out over<b> Pordoselene Bay</b>, which enjoyed a brief interval of fame as the home of a dolphin who saved a drowning boy. Another local unmissable is the breathtaking Patriça Bay, where you’ll find abandoned Greek villages ringed with wildflowers and herbs. <br />\r\n<br />\r\nShoppers should check out the <b>weekly market</b> (köy pazarı) held on Thursdays- keep your eyes open for good deals on knockoff brand name goods and heaping piles of locally-grown food for dirt-cheap prices.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nDefinitely plan an afternoon around the iconic <a href=\"http://taskahve.hikeast.com/\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">Taş Kahve</a>(Sahil Boyu No:20), the island’s most famous coffeehouse by a long shot. The place has been around for decades and has become something of a local landmark.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nFancy some wine\tinstead?\t Go for <a href=\"http://Vino+Şarap+Evi\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">Vino Şarap Evi</a> (Cumhuriyet Cad. No:8), where you can enjoy amazing wine and meze in a relaxed, beautiful atmosphere.",
        "lat": "39.921900077818",
        "lang": "32.860464224724",
        "thumbnail_image": "http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/530109_398215300190896_1006281.jpg",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "_530109_398215300190896_1006281"

            },
            {
                "image": "_529165_398214486857644_6240187"

            },
            {
                "image": "_527163_398214973524262_2108933"

            },
            {
                "image": "_555388_398214660190960_1043994"

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 50,
        "name": "Amasra / Samsun",
        "destination_id": 5,
        "string_info": "<b>Amasra</b><br />\r\nJust two hours from Safranbolu by bus, the sleepy coastal town of Amasra is a historical goldmine minus the crowds you’re likely to find in the Black Sea region’s larger cities. With quiet beaches, two islands for exploration, and a history stretching back to ancient times, Amasra will keep nature-lovers and architecture buffs alike enthralled. The impressive <b>Amasra Castle</b> dates back to Roman rule and owes its eclectic appearance to numerous additions and improvements by various occupiers throughout history. Take some time to visit the Church Mosque as well, which, as the name suggests, has been used for both Christian and Muslim worship in the past.<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<b>How to get to Amasra</b><br />\r\nTo reach Amasra, you can take a bus from Bartın, the most convenient local hub 10 kilometers to the south. From there, it’s an easy connection to Safranbolu. The roads are somewhat run-down in this region, but look at it in a positive light- you might just have the place all to yourself.<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<b>From Amasra to Sinop</b><br />\r\nProbably, as many backpackers, you are looking at the Black Sea map and finding obvious that the best way to go from Amasra to Sinop is by following the coastline. Well, be sure that it is not the best and not the fastest, but surely beautiful and worth it. <br />\r\n<br />\r\nFor the ones travelling with their own car, this way is going to be pleasant, dotted with small  little villagest lost in time. For the ones travelling by public means, start get going, your way is long. If you ask to the locals in Amasra, they will tell you to go back to Bartin, or even Karabuk, and then to Sinop. Don't be discouraged. Wake up early in the morning and wait for the dolmus to <b>Cide</b>. From there, you will have to change and take the dolmus to <b>Inebolu</b>. By the time you reach this small village, you probably will have lost the last dolmus to the next village, <b>Türkeli</b>. There is not too many accommodation options in Inebolu: a pension that serves as a students dormitory during the winter right on the main streat, next to the Ataturk's sculpture, and <b>Otel Ionopoli</b>, Uğur Mumcu Cad. No: 4 (+90366811375556). The following morning you can reach Türkeli and from there take a dolmus to <b>Sinop</b>. <br />\r\n <br />\r\n<br />\r\n<b>Samsun</b><br />\r\nFeaturing prominently in the 20th century history of the Turkish Republic as well as being an important sea port throughout the years, Samsun is nevertheless short on areas of touristic interest. The main exceptions are the two museums in town. The first of these is the Archaeological Museum, displaying an impressive mosaic salvaged from the old settlement of Karasamsun, while the second, the Gazi Museum, is dedicated to Mustafa Kemal Atatürk, the founder of the modern republic.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nHeading east from Samsun, take a drive along the scenic <b>Yason Burnu</b> (Cape Jason), so named for the famous Argonaut. An ancient temple dedicated to the hero is said to have once stood here; now, it has been replaced by a quaint church, well worth a visit.F",
        "lat": "39.921900077818",
        "lang": "32.860464224724",
        "thumbnail_image": "http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/11.jpg",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "_11"
            },
            {
                "image": "_21"
            },
            {
                "image": "_31"
            },
            {
                "image": "_41"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 43,
        "name": "Ankara",
        "destination_id": 4,
        "string_info": "Turkey’s capital city since the early 1920s, Ankara is also the country’s second largest metropolis after İstanbul. You may have been told to steer clear and spend your travel time elsewhere, but don’t be misled; Ankara’s reputation for being boring is greatly overstated and both party-goers and cultural history buffs will find plenty to occupy them. On top of that, it’s an attractive city; many of the shops and restaurants in central Ulus are built in reconstructed buildings from time gone by. You’ll find leather, spices, and other goods for sale in its winding alleys.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nThe <b>Atatürk memorial</b>, Anıtkabir, features huge collections of memorabilia belonging to Turkey’s most celebrated leader and is well worth a visit even if you aren’t typically a museum enthusiast. Take in his extensive sword collection, his impressive library, several of his cars, and even his favorite dog (taxidermied, of course).<br />\r\n<br />\r\nYou can easily spend a day or three visiting Ankara’s many museums, from the <b>METU Science and Technology Museum</b> to the <b>Museum of Anatolian Civilizations</b>. If monumental architecture is more your thing, head up to <b>Ulus</b> and explore the twisting alleys of Ankara’s hilltop castle, filled with small shops and surprises.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nIf you’re in search of a good cafe or a stiffer drink, you’ll want to head to the central district of <b>Kızılay</b>. Bars and teahouses abound here, and many locations transform into booming clubs after dark.<br />\r\n<br />\r\n<b>How to get to Ankara</b><br />\r\nBeing central in terms of both geographical location and political importance, Ankara is easy to reach from anywhere in the country and makes a great hub for further explorations of Turkey and beyond. Arriving by air, you’ll come in 28 kilometers northwest of the city proper. If buses are more your style, you’ll find yourself at the terminal locally known as AŞTİ, connected to the central districts by a metro line.",
        "lat": "39.921900077818",
        "lang": "32.860464224724",
        "thumbnail_image": "http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/003.jpg",
        "images": [
            {
                "image": "_003.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "_002.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "sf122"
            }
        ]
    }]}
```

How can i please access each locations images array from my app? I accessed all other object like this:

```
    String feed = loadJSONFromAsset();
    try {
        JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(feed);
        JSONArray jsonArray = mJsonObj.getJSONArray("locations");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
            int destination_id = jsonObject.getInt("destination_id");
            String info = jsonObject.getString("string_info");
            int unique_id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
            Double lat = jsonObject.getDouble("lat");
            Double lng = jsonObject.getDouble("lang");  

            locationinfo.setName(name);
            locationinfo.setDestionationId(destination_id);
            locationinfo.setInfo(info);
            locationinfo.setId(unique_id);
            locationinfo.setLang(lng);
            locationinfo.setLat(lat);

            if(Locationname.equals(locationinfo.getName())){

                TextView infoText = (TextView) V
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtLocationInformation);
                infoText.setText(Html.fromHtml(locationinfo.getInfo()));



            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am having difficulty knowing how to access the images...can anyone pls help me out with this. thanks.

Comment: u have to do same thing with the outer for loop

Comment: What @sakir said, or use the google gson library: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: images inside the array ("images": []),so u have to write another loop for this array

Comment: @sakir yeah i got it...i actually did that initially but with the answer posted below, i realised my error...thanks tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String feed = loadJSONFromAsset();
try {
    JSONObject mJsonObj = new JSONObject(feed);
    JSONArray jsonArray = mJsonObj.getJSONArray("locations");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
        int destination_id = jsonObject.getInt("destination_id");
        String info = jsonObject.getString("string_info");
        int unique_id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
        Double lat = jsonObject.getDouble("lat");
        Double lng = jsonObject.getDouble("lang");  

        locationinfo.setName(name);
        locationinfo.setDestionationId(destination_id);
        locationinfo.setInfo(info);
        locationinfo.setId(unique_id);
        locationinfo.setLang(lng);
        locationinfo.setLat(lat);

        if(Locationname.equals(locationinfo.getName())){

            TextView infoText = (TextView) V
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtLocationInformation);
            infoText.setText(Html.fromHtml(locationinfo.getInfo()));



        }

        JSONArray images = jsonObject.getJSONArray("images");
        for(int j = 0; j < images.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject image = images.getJSONObject(j);
            Log.d(TAG, image.getString("image"));
        }

    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It is just a simple array inside json. So you can access it with the methods provided by `JSONObject` like `getJSONArray(String name)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
    String jsonString ="{\"locations\":[{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"Alibey Island (Cunda)\",\"destination_id\":2,\"string_info\":\"Otherwise known as Cunda, Alibey Island is connected to Lale Island and Ayvalık by a road bridge. Accordingly, dolmuşes and buses are available from the mainland if you don’t have your own transportation. <br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nOn the north edge of Cunda, look out over<b> Pordoselene Bay</b>, which enjoyed a brief interval of fame as the home of a dolphin who saved a drowning boy. Another local unmissable is the breathtaking Patriça Bay, where you’ll find abandoned Greek villages ringed with wildflowers and herbs. <br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nShoppers should check out the <b>weekly market</b> (köy pazarı) held on Thursdays- keep your eyes open for good deals on knockoff brand name goods and heaping piles of locally-grown food for dirt-cheap prices.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nDefinitely plan an afternoon around the iconic <a href=\\\"http://taskahve.hikeast.com/\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">Taş Kahve</a>(Sahil Boyu No:20), the island’s most famous coffeehouse by a long shot. The place has been around for decades and has become something of a local landmark.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nFancy some wine\\tinstead?\\t Go for <a href=\\\"http://Vino+Şarap+Evi\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\">Vino Şarap Evi</a> (Cumhuriyet Cad. No:8), where you can enjoy amazing wine and meze in a relaxed, beautiful atmosphere.\",\"lat\":\"39.921900077818\",\"lang\":\"32.860464224724\",\"thumbnail_image\":\"http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/530109_398215300190896_1006281.jpg\",\"images\":[{\"image\":\"_530109_398215300190896_1006281\"},{\"image\":\"_529165_398214486857644_6240187\"},{\"image\":\"_527163_398214973524262_2108933\"},{\"image\":\"_555388_398214660190960_1043994\"}]},{\"id\":50,\"name\":\"Amasra / Samsun\",\"destination_id\":5,\"string_info\":\"<b>Amasra</b><br />\\r\\nJust two hours from Safranbolu by bus, the sleepy coastal town of Amasra is a historical goldmine minus the crowds you’re likely to find in the Black Sea region’s larger cities. With quiet beaches, two islands for exploration, and a history stretching back to ancient times, Amasra will keep nature-lovers and architecture buffs alike enthralled. The impressive <b>Amasra Castle</b> dates back to Roman rule and owes its eclectic appearance to numerous additions and improvements by various occupiers throughout history. Take some time to visit the Church Mosque as well, which, as the name suggests, has been used for both Christian and Muslim worship in the past.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\n<b>How to get to Amasra</b><br />\\r\\nTo reach Amasra, you can take a bus from Bartın, the most convenient local hub 10 kilometers to the south. From there, it’s an easy connection to Safranbolu. The roads are somewhat run-down in this region, but look at it in a positive light- you might just have the place all to yourself.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\n<b>From Amasra to Sinop</b><br />\\r\\nProbably, as many backpackers, you are looking at the Black Sea map and finding obvious that the best way to go from Amasra to Sinop is by following the coastline. Well, be sure that it is not the best and not the fastest, but surely beautiful and worth it. <br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nFor the ones travelling with their own car, this way is going to be pleasant, dotted with small  little villagest lost in time. For the ones travelling by public means, start get going, your way is long. If you ask to the locals in Amasra, they will tell you to go back to Bartin, or even Karabuk, and then to Sinop. Don't be discouraged. Wake up early in the morning and wait for the dolmus to <b>Cide</b>. From there, you will have to change and take the dolmus to <b>Inebolu</b>. By the time you reach this small village, you probably will have lost the last dolmus to the next village, <b>Türkeli</b>. There is not too many accommodation options in Inebolu: a pension that serves as a students dormitory during the winter right on the main streat, next to the Ataturk's sculpture, and <b>Otel Ionopoli</b>, Uğur Mumcu Cad. No: 4 (+90366811375556). The following morning you can reach Türkeli and from there take a dolmus to <b>Sinop</b>. <br />\\r\\n <br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\n<b>Samsun</b><br />\\r\\nFeaturing prominently in the 20th century history of the Turkish Republic as well as being an important sea port throughout the years, Samsun is nevertheless short on areas of touristic interest. The main exceptions are the two museums in town. The first of these is the Archaeological Museum, displaying an impressive mosaic salvaged from the old settlement of Karasamsun, while the second, the Gazi Museum, is dedicated to Mustafa Kemal Atatürk, the founder of the modern republic.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nHeading east from Samsun, take a drive along the scenic <b>Yason Burnu</b> (Cape Jason), so named for the famous Argonaut. An ancient temple dedicated to the hero is said to have once stood here; now, it has been replaced by a quaint church, well worth a visit.F\",\"lat\":\"39.921900077818\",\"lang\":\"32.860464224724\",\"thumbnail_image\":\"http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/11.jpg\",\"images\":[{\"image\":\"_11\"},{\"image\":\"_21\"},{\"image\":\"_31\"},{\"image\":\"_41\"}]},{\"id\":43,\"name\":\"Ankara\",\"destination_id\":4,\"string_info\":\"Turkey’s capital city since the early 1920s, Ankara is also the country’s second largest metropolis after İstanbul. You may have been told to steer clear and spend your travel time elsewhere, but don’t be misled; Ankara’s reputation for being boring is greatly overstated and both party-goers and cultural history buffs will find plenty to occupy them. On top of that, it’s an attractive city; many of the shops and restaurants in central Ulus are built in reconstructed buildings from time gone by. You’ll find leather, spices, and other goods for sale in its winding alleys.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nThe <b>Atatürk memorial</b>, Anıtkabir, features huge collections of memorabilia belonging to Turkey’s most celebrated leader and is well worth a visit even if you aren’t typically a museum enthusiast. Take in his extensive sword collection, his impressive library, several of his cars, and even his favorite dog (taxidermied, of course).<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nYou can easily spend a day or three visiting Ankara’s many museums, from the <b>METU Science and Technology Museum</b> to the <b>Museum of Anatolian Civilizations</b>. If monumental architecture is more your thing, head up to <b>Ulus</b> and explore the twisting alleys of Ankara’s hilltop castle, filled with small shops and surprises.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\nIf you’re in search of a good cafe or a stiffer drink, you’ll want to head to the central district of <b>Kızılay</b>. Bars and teahouses abound here, and many locations transform into booming clubs after dark.<br />\\r\\n<br />\\r\\n<b>How to get to Ankara</b><br />\\r\\nBeing central in terms of both geographical location and political importance, Ankara is easy to reach from anywhere in the country and makes a great hub for further explorations of Turkey and beyond. Arriving by air, you’ll come in 28 kilometers northwest of the city proper. If buses are more your style, you’ll find yourself at the terminal locally known as AŞTİ, connected to the central districts by a metro line.\",\"lat\":\"39.921900077818\",\"lang\":\"32.860464224724\",\"thumbnail_image\":\"http://www.hikeast.com/r/location/t/003.jpg\",\"images\":[{\"image\":\"_003.jpg\"},{\"image\":\"_002.jpg\"},{\"image\":\"sf122\"}]}]}";

    JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    JSONArray locationsJsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("locations");
    for (int i=0;i<locationsJsonArray.length();i++){
         HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
         row.put("id",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
         row.put("name",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
         row.put("destination_id",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("destination_id"));
         row.put("lat",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat"));
         row.put("lang",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lang"));
         row.put("thumbnail_image",locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("thumbnail_image"));

         JSONArray imagesJsonArray = locationsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("images");
         ArrayList<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int j=0; j<imagesJsonArray.length(); j++){
             imagesList.add(imagesJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("image"));
         }
         row.put("images",imagesList);
         data.add(row);
    }

    for (HashMap<String,Object> row :data){
         System.out.print("id : "+row.get("id").toString());
         System.out.print("name : "+row.get("name").toString());
         System.out.print("destination_id : "+row.get("destination_id").toString());
         System.out.print("lat : "+row.get("lat").toString());
         System.out.print("lang : "+row.get("lang").toString());
         System.out.print("thumbnail_image : "+row.get("thumbnail_image").toString());

         ArrayList<String> jobs = (ArrayList<String>) row.get("images");
         for (String image :jobs){
              System.out.print("image : "+image);
          }
     }
}catch (Throwable e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```